# How to use AMFPHP functions from .NET WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, php, wpf, amfphp

How to use AMFPHP functions from .NET WPF application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FluorineFx](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) implements an AMF client for .net (including silverlight).
You might also be interested in [WebORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products.html)